# Gitlab where is config.toml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-runner

Im working on adding code quality to gitlab.
one of the step requires making changes to config.toml.

I have .gitlab-ci.yml at root level of project repository.and pipeline picks up this file.

where do i define config.toml ? at root level or i need to create a new folder like
/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

Answer (score 20):

The `config.toml` file is what configures a runner. You wouldn't have one unless you're running your own gitlab-runners, in which case it would be in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` on the host running the runner. More information on Gitlab Runner and running it yourself is available [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/).

Comment: In my case the config file was in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

Comment: Thanks @sneaky, I was remembering it wrong at the time I wrote this. I've updated my answer with the correct location.

Answer (score 3):

The locations where it could be is documented [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html).

> You can find the config.toml file in:
>
> - /etc/gitlab-runner/ on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as root (this is also the path for service configuration)
> - ~/.gitlab-runner/ on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as non-root
> - ./ on other systems

But if your Run GitLab Runner in a **Docker** container, your config is located at

- `/etc/gitlab-runner`

inside the GitLab Runner Docker container filesystem.
This will correspond to the location

- `/srv/gitlab-runner/config`

of your host file system if the container was started as described in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html)

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always \
  -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using shared runners (the default), then you need not worry about any settings in that file.

config.toml comes into the picture only if you are setting up your own runner. You should not need to create config.toml  - it gets created for you when you install your own runner.