# Gitlab runner configuration on windows

Tags: powershell, gitlab, pipeline, executor, runner

i am trying to use gitlab runner installed on my windows machine . But pipeline execution fails with error:
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: failed to start process: exec: "pwsh": executable file not found in %PATH%. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information

I am using "shell" as executor while registering runner.
I have also setup path variables correctly.

I have setup path varialbes correctly in system variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root directory of your gitlab runner installation, often `c:\gitlab-runner` you'll see a config.toml file.  You need to change pwsh (powershell core) to powershell (powershell).

```
[[runners]]
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "pwsh"
```

to

```
[[runners]]
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
```

See also:

- [Gitlab where is config.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68830713/gitlab-where-is-config-toml)