# How to increase shm_size for gitlab runner inside AWS on EC2 instances?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm building the Gitlab CI/CD pipeline. To be able to run the tests in test and in prod (for post-deployment testing) I've created two different environments - test and production.
I write the code for tests in Robot Framework with Selenium on Python.
The tests are failing on Capture Page Screenshot because of the page crash:
`[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: InvalidSessionIdException: Message: invalid session id | FAIL | WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.61)`
After googling a lot, my assumption is that, after I created a new environment, shared runners are low on memory to be able to capture and store the page screenshots.
I don't have dockerfile.
I have gitlab-ci.yml file with reference to AWS docker image, which is located on AWS ECR.

I've checked this page: [unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed with ChromeDriver Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902507/unknown-error-session-deleted-because-of-page-crash-from-unknown-error-cannot), but that's not my case, because to be able to increase shm_size, I need to have a config.toml file, as described here: [Gitlab where is config.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68830713/gitlab-where-is-config-toml) , but I can't locate one. I don't have .toml file, because gitlab executes on AWS EC2 instances.
Me and development team checked that size of EC2 instances is 8G, which is more than enough I guess.
I also tried to add the shm_size variable or DOCKER_SHM_SIZE: 1100000000 in variables section of the job, but that didn't work.

So my question is: how can I increase the shared memory of the runners in that case?
And am I on the right path of troubleshooting?
I would really-really appreciate any help! Because I was struggling with that issue for awhile.....

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? Do I need to provide more details?